# pycrfsuite : how to recall the saved models for more training

Tags: methods, python-2.x, python-crfsuite

I am using pycrfsuite now.
I Know crf training model's saving.

```
crf_trainer = pycrfsuite.Trainer()
crf_trainer.train('crf.crfsuite')
```

So, When I want to tag, i use the source.

```
crf_tagger = pycrfsuite.Tagger()
crf_tagger.open('crf.crfsuite')
```

But, I don't know how to recall the saved models for more training.